# Как убрать во второй колонке грида расширение высоты пропорционально первой?

Tags: html, css

При нажатии на блок в любом ряду, где их двое, второй расширяет свою высоту относительно первого. Как это убрать?

```
    
.box{
  width: 646px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 24px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 64px;
}
```

[Соурс](https://codepen.io/luxurypluxury/pen/LYXwLoa)